# Is there a simpler or cleaner way to find an object in an object array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

Say we have one object called "myDroid" and a list of objects called "droids", and I am looking for a particular droid called Alfred. If Alfred is in the list I want a boolean value to be set to true.

This is my solutions to find it:

```
for(i in droids) {
    if(droids[i].name === myDroid.name) {
        foundIt = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler or cleaner way to do this in Javascript? Or is this the simplest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var foundIt = droids.some(function (droid) {
  return droid.name === myDroid.name;
});
```